# Laravel memcached

Tags: macos, memcached, laravel-7

I am getting error like this
php artisan cache:clear

> Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.

in my .env

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

i have storage/framework/cache/data directory

in my Macbook m1
brew services info memcached
memcached (homebrew.mxcl.memcached)
Running: ✔
Loaded: ✔

how can i solve the problem?

I tried to add a php extension for memcached like extension=memcached.so, but it didn't help.
tried to restart memcached (brew services restart memcached), it also not helped. i do not know how to solve this problem, anyone knows the reason of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happened in my case, problem was related with memcached port.

1. Check you config.cache.php file if default value is 11211

```
...
'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
...
```

2. Check your .env file you may have MEMCACHED_PORT variable with different value, remove it or set

```
...
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211
...
```

if default is not exists in config file